# People say sys.path is needed to import. But import works BEFORE importing sys, ie before sys.path exists. How?

Tags: python, import, sys.path

According to many help posts, python uses the list `sys.path` (hereafter called SP) to import modules. Another frequent claim is that SP is auto created every time python starts.
This is clearly not exactly true as one can do imports before SP exists, then it appears to be able to find modules at least in the same directory and in the system library.
In particular, it can use import to find the sys module which creates SP.
So where does python look before SP is created?
And does SP supersede the default way of finding modules, or do they both operate in tandem?
Can one specify how to find a module without the aid of sys?

Comment: It's used internally, you don't have to import it.

Comment: You only have to import it if you want to show or update the value.

Answer (score -1):

Python does not use `sys.path` to search for modules, `sys.path` provides a programmatic way to see the directories that the interpreter is looking in to import modules. Those paths are already determined by your environment regardless if `sys.path` is called at all.